# Scroll on iframe passed to parent page but wheel event not fired?

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll, mousewheel

I am embedding a youtube video on my page, initially the page was not scrolling at all whenever the user used to scroll over it. But after fixing it with some css, the scrolling is passed from the iframe to the parent page but the `wheel event` is not being fired. I have added some custom scrolling behavior on my webpage by listening to the `wheel` event but this unusual scroll passing behavior is breaking it.

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {

}
```

Also, tried the `onwheel` event, but even that is not fired.

```
window.onwheel = function (e) {

}
```